# Accessing gridview from a non GridView event

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a button outside a gridview called "UpdateAll", i need to be able to click on such button and find an item template "DropDownList" and update the database with that value for each record, I am not sure how to go about this any ideas?

```
  public void UpdateAll_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}
```

Now I know I can access the drop down in the GridView_RowCommand something like this

```
  GridViewRow row = (GridViewRow)(((Button)e.CommandSource).NamingContainer);
        Myddl = row.FindControl("Quantity") as DropDownList;
```

But i am not sure how to do that from an outside event that is not GridView related, I can not do the one above because it accesses the `e.CommandSource.`

Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this;

```
for(int rowIndex =0; rowIndex<gv.rows.count; rowIndex++)
{
  Myddl = gv.rows[rowIndex].FindControl("Quantity") as DropDownList;

}
```